# No aparecen los encabezados JAVA

Tags: java

[image: En la imagen se ve como al agregar la información a la columna si aparecen los valores escritos, pero no los nombres que le puse a los encabezados como por ejemplo "id","nombre",etc.;]

¿Cómo puedo solucionar un problema en mi código que no muestra los nombres de las columnas que he puesto en un DataFrame?
Estoy utilizando un DefaultTableModel para agregar columnas y filas a una tabla en Java.
Aunque los valores se agregan correctamente a las columnas, los encabezados de las columnas no aparece y aunque las filas se agregan correctamente, los encabezados de las columnas no aparecen. He verificado que los nombres de las columnas se agreguen correctamente utilizando el método addColumn() del modelo de tabla.
¿Qué cambios puedo hacer para asegurarme de que los nombres de las columnas aparezcan primero en el DataFrame y luego todos los valores que se agreguen se muestren debajo de sus respectivos encabezados?

Este seria mi codigo:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Stock {
    private JPanel panelStock;
    private JButton stockButton;
    private JButton facturarButton;
    private JButton proveedoresButton;
    private JButton clientesButton1;
    private JButton empleadosButton;
    private JButton agregarButton;
    private JButton modificarButton;
    private JButton eliminarButton;
    private JTextField IDtextField1;
    private JTextField NombretextField2;
    private JTextField PreciotextField3;
    private JTextField CantidadtextField4;
    private JTextField ProveedortextField5;
    private JTextField DetallestextField6;
    private JTable table1;
    private DefaultTableModel tbl;

    public Stock() {
        DefaultTableModel tbl = new DefaultTableModel();
        tbl.addColumn("ID");
        tbl.addColumn("Nombre");
        tbl.addColumn("Precio");
        tbl.addColumn("Cantidad");
        tbl.addColumn("Proveedor");
        tbl.addColumn("Detalles");
        table1.setModel(tbl); // establecer el modelo de la tabla



        facturarButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    facturacion fac = new facturacion();
                    fac.setVisible(true);


            }
        });
        proveedoresButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Proveedores pr = new Proveedores();
                pr.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        clientesButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Clientes cl = new Clientes();
                cl.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
        empleadosButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Empleados emp = new Empleados();
                emp.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        stockButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                StockBoton stb = new StockBoton();
                stb.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        agregarButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DefaultTableModel tbl = (DefaultTableModel) table1.getModel();
                Object[] fila = new Object[6];
                fila[0] = IDtextField1.getText();
                fila[1] = NombretextField2.getText();
                fila[2] = PreciotextField3. getText();
                fila[3] = CantidadtextField4.getText();
                fila[4] = ProveedortextField5.getText();
                fila[5] = DetallestextField6.getText();
                tbl.addRow(fila);

            }
        });
    }

    private void add(JScrollPane scrollPane, String center) {
        
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean b) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lista");
        frame.setContentPane(new Stock().panelStock);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Milagros, para que un `JTable` muestre los nombres de las columnas, debes meterlo dentro de un `JScrollPane`, por ejemplo: **JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane( tabla1 );**